# Function not loading on page

Tags: jquery

Click event with jquery function is not working when it is before the a tag but it is working fine after the a tag. Also, if I use `document.ready` then it works. I would like to know why it is not working when it is before the a tag.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function jchand(){
            $('a').click(function(){
                alert('a')
            })
        }
        jchand();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" >click me</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element doesn't exist when you try to bind `.click`, as the page has not yet finished loading.

> another thing If i am using document .ready then it is working

Well, this is exactly what `$(document).ready` is *for*:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a').click(function()
    {
        alert('a');
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function()
{
    alert('a');
});
```

which binds to the entire document instead, and so will work for any elements added in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`$('a')` looks for `<a>` elements, but the DOM isn't ready. Use `$(document).ready()` to create a callback function that gets triggered when the DOM is actually ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
        alert('a');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue is that jchand() is executing before the `<a>` element exists.  Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
alert('a')
})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because script is getting called before a is loaded in DOM. At that point, it doesn't see any 'a' elements to attach click elements. Though function declaration is ok, but it must be called after 'a'.

document.ready function calls the script after all elements of the page are loaded, so it gets fired.

Answer (score 0):

Your script executes before the DOM is ready. It will work if you call the function on document ready (`$(document).ready(function())` or `$(function())`) like this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jchand(){
        $('a').click(function(){
            alert('a')
        })
    }

    $(function() {
        jchand();
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" >click me</a>
</body>
```